Searching for part of a String within an Array
The below code works well to filter books by author but only works when search string is equal to full string.  Example where authors contains full names, e.g. ["Jack Nicklaus", "Arnold Palmer", "Sam Snead"]
How do I allow search bar to filter based on part of name and not case sensitive, example "Nicklaus"
var filteredBooksByAuthor: [Book] {
    if searchTextAuthor.isEmpty {
        books
    } else {
        books.filter { $0.authors.contains(searchTextAuthor) }
    }
}


You could reduce the authors of a book and filter on that.
import Foundation

let searchTextAuthor = "PalmER"
let filteredBooks: [Book]

if searchTextAuthor.isEmpty {
    filteredBooks = books
} else {
    filteredBooks = books.filter { b in
        b.authors.reduce("") { partialResult, author in
            partialResult + " \(author)"
        }.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTextAuthor)
    }
}


Your reduce(_:into:) is a complex way for writing b.authros.joined(separator: " ") (Plus adding a space as the start). Also, now, depending on the user needs, but if you search for "palmer sam" your code should return that book, which might not be the expected behavior.

You would use localizedCaseInsensitiveContains. Toy example just to demonstrate that it works:
let authors = ["Jack Nicklaus", "Arnold Palmer", "Sam Snead"]
let filteredAuthors = authors.filter { 
    $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("nicklaus") 
}
print(filteredAuthors) // ["Jack Nicklaus"]

It should be obvious how to adapt that to your use case, i.e. where it is books that needs to be filtered based on its authors property.
